# FIFO throughput subject to process' `nice` value

Tags: linux, pipe, overloading, scheduling

It seems the kernel handles the data traveling thru named pipes (FIFOs) between two processes independently from the `nice` value assigned to such processes. This is particularly evident in the following case, where the system is overloaded with a lot of concurrent processes to handle.

The processes A and B communicate via FIFOs; they have a higher task priority (lower nice) than all the other processes demanding high CPU usage. The system is permanently overloaded; when there is no communication between A and B via the FIFOs, these two processes get the most of the CPU sacrificing the lower priority processes. But when FIFO communication begins, A and B, still demanding lots of CPU, are set apart by the kernel, and processes with higher nice (nice 10 units higher) get nearly all the CPU.

It seems the kernel is unable to schedule the handling of the FIFOs accordingly to the nice of processes using them, and, when the system is overloaded, the kernel handles the FIFOs with no special priority.

Is this the case?

Comment: How much data are you writing at one time? FIFO buffers are fairly small, so perhaps your processes are getting blocked on waiting for space to become available.

Comment: Data is really small, a few bytes per second, but the system has a load of 3 (single core). I don't think the buffer is being flooded (it should be 32KB here).